# Multiple files in a single field model of Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am making a site in which user uploads it's pdf and back of the site we generate audio file for each page and now we want to save it on the database(mysql).
Now the problem starts we have model in django and model have the fields which are for a single input.
**for example**

```
class Info(models.Model):
    phone_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    RAM = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    ROM = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    Cost = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    Link = models.URLField(max_length=250)
```

Now if we use  `models.FileField(upload_to='files')` then it will upload files to a files folder but I have several files then how to upload that files, because we can't create fields for that and if we create fields for that then it's not fix that the user uploaded pdf have the same no. of pages as we have fields.

Answer (score 0):

Create another model "PhoneIMG" with a ForeignKey to "Info". Then you can have as many files as you want that are connected to the "Info" model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another model to store that files and linked that model to your **Infor** model as **ManyToMany** field. for example

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    phone_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='/location')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

and then link the model with your **Info** model as follow

```
class Info(models.Model):
    phone_img = models.ManyToManyField(UploadFile)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    RAM = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    ROM = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    Cost = models.IntegerField(default= None)
    Link = models.URLField(max_length=250)
```

for more information please visit the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: dude my problem is that I have files in a folder of project and that folder is on my machine so now how I upload this files to database and I can't directly upload that files to database using form or some other method Because I am taking a pdf from the user and converting audio file of each page and that pages audio file is saved in static folder of project so from that folder to database. how to upload. Sorry my question was not explained well.

Comment: Please help me out :(

Comment: can you show your upload view code?

Comment: https://github.com/Kanharajput/OnlyListen/blob/master/Home/views.py

Comment: Above link is of view code. And you can  also check the whole project code to understand it better. Thanks